# Parallel using spark

Tags: parallel-processing

I have method `A()` to compare a pair of 3D structure of proteins ( 3D objects). I would like to repeat this method for `10000000 times` for `10000000 pairs` of protein. One protein description is in one text file, they are separated.
How can parallel the repeated method using spark?
Thank for your help.

Comment: For starters, you can [load the files into an RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029873/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd) and use a DataFrame with a user defined function that applies A() to the columns of the DataFrame to make comparisons. More details are necessary to formulate a full example, but for the parallelization you can take a look at [this](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/2119/how-do-i-process-several-rdds-all-at-once.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069239/parallelize-avoid-foreach-loop-in-spark)

Comment: hi mkaran,
Method A()
  i) read 2 text files, extract 3D coordinates , and information
  ii) find maxiu clique
  iii)  save result to arrayrepeat A() for 1000000 pairs

Comment: A() is very fast though it might has  computational bottleneck with large file, and spark will help here. But the real problem is repeat A() 100000 times. I usually use adhoc multithreading with Thread pool with 10 threads concurrently. My question is 1)my adhoc implementation can run in cluster of thousand of nodes? I think it can run only on my typical PC  2 core Ram 4G 2) How to implement it in spark 
Thanks much