# How to paralelize spark etl more w/out losing info (in file names)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm going over a list of files on HDFS one by one, opening it as text and then saving back to HDFS, to another location. Data is being parsed, then *part* files are merged and saved to same name as original, with BZIP2 suffix. However, it's rather slow - takes ~3s for each file, and I have over 10,000 of them per folder. I need to go file by file because I'm unsure how to *keep* the file name information. I need name to be able to do a MD5 and "confirm" no information loss has happened.

Here's my code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, FileUtil}
import org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
import org.apache.spark.sql._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._ 
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext} 

sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress", "true")
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", "true")
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", 
               "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec")
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.type", "BLOCK")

val hdfsConf = SparkHadoopUtil.get.newConfiguration(sc.getConf)
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hdfsConf)
val sourcePath = new Path("/source/*20180801*") 

hdfs.globStatus(sourcePath).foreach( fileStatus => {
  val fileName = fileStatus.getPath().getName()
  val filePathName = fileStatus.getPath().toString
  if (fileName.contains(".done")) {
    /* open, then save compressed */
    val myFile = sc.textFile(filePathName)
    val compressedBasePath = "/destination/compressed/"
    /* use tmp_ to store folder w/ parts in it */
    val compressedPath = compressedBasePath + "tmp_/" + fileName
    myFile.saveAsTextFile(compressedPath, 
                          classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec])
    /* merge part* -> old_name.bzip */
    FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(compressedPath), hdfs, 
                       new Path(compressedBasePath + "/" + fileName + ".bzip2"), 
                       true, hdfsConf, null)
    myFile.unpersist()
  }
})
```

Before I figured I *need* the tests, I used something like this:

```
val myFile = sc.textFile("/source/*20180801*")
myFile.saveAsTextFile(compressedPath, 
                      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec])
```

But then I cannot do the renaming part, and I do need the names. 
Any ideas what I could do?

UPDATE: 
Thanks to suggestions in comments, and [this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069239/parallelize-avoid-foreach-loop-in-spark), I was able to fix the issue using parallel collections. The only real change was import of `import scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector` and adding `par` method call before doing the `foreach`.

Full article about parallel collections: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html

Thx

Comment: Checking for loss of data. I did that 30 years ago. I that time not past us that we need to do that? Curious.

Comment: I get it, but data is of significance... user records... and i just have to somehow give "proof" all is clear before I actually start removing it :)

Comment: Why not store in an RDD the list of files, repartition it and then convert logic to run as part of foreachPartition or mapPartitions?

Comment: Its a little contrived and not quite in the spirit of Spark parallel processing. But will work. What about Scala program with Futures? Bzip2 thing ...

Comment: Let us know how you go

Comment: Sorry for the _silence time_, but I had to take my beauty sleep :)... I've been sitting on this for quite some time. I'm a bit puzzled on the approach you explained. Have some code samples?

Comment: Look at mapPartitions example, you make iterators and can execute things in parallel, by taking part of an RDD. As I said this is not a standard case. But you are now getting sequential file by file processing. Unless I am wrong on foreach

Comment: Yes, and that's why it's slow as a snail uphill. Okay, I'll try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069239/parallelize-avoid-foreach-loop-in-spark

Comment: This did the trick. Actually, I parallelized using parallel collections, as described in second answer and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Perhaps share the code for others. I am interested in contrasting as well. The RDD foreach would also work, but...  I.e. answer your own question - with help from others admittedly. Right the.par looks interesting. I was thinking about Futures, looks quite easy. Speed up comparison is?

Comment: I'm not at liberty of modifying yarn setup, so it was a blocker for me sort of. I also added an answer.

Comment: Good on you. Will help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two potential solutions in the original question's comments:

- use Future (Q: [Parallelize / avoid foreach loop in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069239/parallelize-avoid-foreach-loop-in-spark))
- use parallel collections (came from same Q, but another answer)

TBH, I only tested second approach as it was a quicker one (with less warnings). Final solution required only minimal changes - import of appropriate lib and parallelization of the Array `hdfs.globStatus(sourcePath)` call was returning. Here's the final code, with comments removed and two comments added for easier spotting of changes.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, FileUtil}
import org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
import org.apache.spark.sql._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._ 
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext} 
import scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector /* added */

sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress", "true")
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", "true")
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec", 
               "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec")
sc.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.type", "BLOCK")

val hdfsConf = SparkHadoopUtil.get.newConfiguration(sc.getConf)
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hdfsConf)
val sourcePath = new Path("/source/*20180801*") 

/* note the par method call below */
hdfs.globStatus(sourcePath).par.foreach( fileStatus => {
  val fileName = fileStatus.getPath().getName()
  val filePathName = fileStatus.getPath().toString
  if (fileName.contains(".done")) {
    val myFile = sc.textFile(filePathName)
    val compressedBasePath = "/destination/compressed/"
    val compressedPath = compressedBasePath + "tmp_/" + fileName
    myFile.saveAsTextFile(compressedPath, 
                          classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec])
    FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(compressedPath), hdfs, 
                       new Path(compressedBasePath + "/" + 
                                fileName.replace(".done", ".done.bz2")), 
                       true, hdfsConf, null)
    myFile.unpersist()
  }
})
```

Comment: Only point to make is - without losing info in title - how did you see that?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - how did I see *what*

Comment: The title says: How to paralelize spark etl more w/out losing info. What does w/out losing info signify? may be I am missing something

Comment: Oh ... OK... If you do a simple `val myFile = sc.textFile("/source/*20180801*"); myFile.saveAsTextFile(compressedPath, classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec])`, the job will also be done, but you'll have part-00001, ... However, I'm then losing file names and ability to verify results.

Comment: I guessed that but semantically not correct in title, could cause confusion. I really like his question. We do most file i/o with LINUX and IMPALA stuff and SPARK for clear use cases. It actually is improving my thoughts that most things can be done in SPARK / SCALA. Although mapping business rules seem clearer in IMPALA QL.

Comment: Found one more interesting thing :). IF you don't use .bz2 as a file extension, spark will not be able to read it correctly usin `sc.textFile(...)`. Updating the answer

Comment: Regarding your Impala QL comment... Unfortunately, I had to go through all this because these were just temp files for processing into Hive. However, this processing took a while and I have no more space :)

Comment: Interesting. Success