# SparkContext can only be used on the driver

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use SparkContext.binaryFiles function to process a set of ZIP files.  The setup is to map from a RDD of filenames, in which the mapping function uses the binaryFiles function.

The problem is that SparkContext is referenced in the mapping function, and I'm getting this error. How can I fix it?

*PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.*

Sample code:

`file_list_rdd.map(lambda x: sc.binaryFiles("/FileStore/tables/xyz/" + x[1]))`

where `file_list_rdd` is a RDD of (id, filename) tuples.

Comment: Actually, in the practical world. We are rarely ( almost don't) transfer SparkContext object from driver to workers. So why do you need to do that?

Comment: That's because the binaryFiles function is only available in the SparkContext class...  See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html

Comment: Can you share some code please. This is a well-known issue to consider.

Comment: Updated question with sample code.  I think my issue is that I want to have two levels - for each row in the top-level RDD, I want to  create a new RDD.  But, the only way to create RDD's is to use SparkContext and yet I cannot use SparkContext there...

Comment: Any value, the answer that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you need to call the function without referencing the spark context - and if that is actually applicable.

Also consider moving the function / def into the map body statement(s) itself. That is commonly done - and we are using a functional language. I have been at a loss to resolve Serialization errors unless I resort to the aforementioned and move defs to the Executor logic.

Some file processing is also done via the driver. This post could be of interest: [How to paralelize spark etl more w/out losing info (in file names)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864171/how-to-paralelize-spark-etl-more-w-out-losing-info-in-file-names/51874273). Based on your code snippet I would be looking at this here.

And you should use something like this and process accordingly:

```
 zip_data = sc.binaryFiles('/user/path-to-folder-with-zips/*.zip')
```

Now you are using it from the Driver and the sc.

Comment: Pretty sure that cannot be done, and you get an error. Look at that link I sent I would suggest.

Comment: SparkContext can only be used on the driver. When you invoke map you are on an Executor. The link I sent you runs parallel collection and is invoked from the Driver, also doing some zipping stuff. I discussed this with that person on that question as that is what became of it. That is the correct approach imho.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance